# Что такое SRNP номер

Tags: windows, microsoft-store

Я разработчик Microsoft Store.
Столкнулся с непонятной проблеммой налогового профиля.
Недавно мне пришло письмо от Microsoft, в котором было написано, что мой налоговый профиль истекает и мне нужно было обновить инофрмацию о налоговом профиле.
При заполнении формы от Майкрософт столкнулся с полем в котором нужно было указать SRNP номер.
Подскажите пожалуйста что это. Я вписал туда свой идентификационный код, пишет что верификацию прошло но срок всё равно истекает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У этой немаленькой компании есть очень важная служба - служба поддержки. Скажите, поддержка Вам отказывается помогать?

Comment: Они не дают поддержку по таким вопросам.

Comment: Если бы меня проконсультировали в Майкрософт я бы не обращался на Stack Overflow.